# Where can I found Kobuki schematics?

Tags: kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My kobuki shows no signs of life, all I hae is voltage on frontal panel when I turn it on. Now I need scematics to try to fix it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268232/where-can-i-found-kobuki-schematics?/) by [Mihtat](https://answers.ros.org/users/31467/mihtat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know schematics for the Kobuki are not available. You'll need to contact Yujin Robot for more information.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0